# Stack Exchange site for questions related to reverse osmosis water filtration?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am interested in reverse osmosis water filtration.

What will be the most suitable site/page of Stack Exchange to accept questions of this topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am interested in Reverse Osmosis Water filtration ...

Click here:

[image: Main Site Selector]

Type your search into the Search Bar: [Reverse Osmosis Water filtration](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=Reverse%20Osmosis%20Water%20filtration)

The suggestions offered are:

1. [DIY.SE](https://diy.stackexchange.com/search?q=Reverse%20Osmosis) - Home Improvement - 86 results
2. [Homebrew.SE](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/search?q=reverse%20osmosis) - Home Brewing - 34 results
3. [MedicalSciences.SE](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/search?q=reverse%20osmosis) - Medical Sciences - 6 results
4. [Chemistry.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=reverse%20osmosis) - Chemistry - 43 results
5. [WorldBuilding.SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=reverse%20osmosis) - World Building (Fictional) - 26 results
6. [Judaism.SE](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=reverse%20osmosis) - Mi Yodeya - 3 results
7. [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=reverse%20osmosis) - Physics - 15 results
8. [Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=reverse%20osmosis) - Travel - 14 results
9. [Cooking.SE](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/search?q=reverse%20osmosis) - Seasoned Advice - 10 results
10. [Outdoors.SE](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/search?q=reverse%20osmosis) - The Great Outdoors - 13 results
11. [Pets.SE](https://pets.stackexchange.com/search?q=reverse%20osmosis) - Pets - 8 results
12. [Engineering.SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=reverse%20osmosis) - Engineering - 11 results
13. [Coffee.SE](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/search?q=reverse%20osmosis) - Coffee - 5 results
14. [Sustainability.SE](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/search?q=reverse%20osmosis) - Sustainable Living - 11 results

Exactly where to ask depends upon exactly what you want to know.

Please ask on a single site whenever possible. If you must ask the same question on more than one site because your specific requirements dictate such a need always include a link (using "Share" link) to your other questions

Answer (score 1):

I typed "Reverse Osmosis Water filtration Stack" into Google.com and found two sites that may be possibilities:

- Chemistry: [Does Reverse Osmosis remove elemental ions from water?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/38742/does-reverse-osmosis-remove-elemental-ions-from-water)
- DIY: [Does a reverse osmosis system drain constantly?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/32066/does-a-reverse-osmosis-system-drain-constantly)